# How can I make a webpage to be shown when a icon/image is clicked in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, webview, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a GridView layout that contain 3 images/icons. What I am trying to do is that whenever an item is clicked, a website page(Webview) should be displayed. 
Here is what I did:

1. In the main.xml file defined the GridView and the WebView layout with LinearLayout as the root element.
2. In the Androidmanifest.xml file gave the permission for Internet access
3. Wrote code for gridview
4. Wrote code for Webview.
5. In the GridView, under the setOnItemClickListener, gave the url for webpage to be displayed using the loadUrl()

So the question: "How can I make a webpage to be shown when I icon/image is clicked?"
*I am able to see the UI on the emulator. But there is no response on clicking an icon. I did something wrong with the onClickItem() event I suppose.*

Thank you for your time.
I wrote the following code:

```
package prototype.wenview.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    // Images to display-----------------------//
    Integer[] imageIds =    {           R.drawable.market,          R.drawable.news,            R.drawable.weather    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //calls the method from super class Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.main);          //sets the UI

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);// Bring gridView into context from main.xml
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
                        {
                WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=hi&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kvk.pravara.com%2Fweather.html");
                        }
                    }
                    );  //setOnItemClickListener declaration ends here.
     }  //onCreate() ends here.

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context; // Context class object - context

        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            context = c;
        }

        //return number of images
        public int getCount()
        {
            return imageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position)     // return type of getItem method is an Object
        {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        //returns an ImageView view--------------
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            }

            else
            {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);
            return imageView;
        }       
    }    
}
```

XML CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"

/>

<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>    

</LinearLayout>
```

/* XML code for Activity2.java. This page intends to display the webpage after an icon in the grid view is clicked. */

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

// Java code for Activity 2

package in.niteesh.MultipleActivities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity 
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         //calls the method from super class Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);          //sets the UI
    }
}
```

// AndroidManifest.xml file where I mentioned presence of Activity2

```
<activity android:name=".Activity2" android:label="Activity 2">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

// In MainActivity class under onItemClick I wrote the following code for webpage to be //shown in second Activity

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
String url = "http://google.com/";  
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));  
        startActivity(new Intent("net.learn2develop.ACTIVITY2"));//reference to start the activity
}
```

/*Now the problem is - After clicking an icon, it switches to Activity2 but no webpage is shown. I tried various turn-arounds but could not find the solution*/

Comment: You might need to add the main.xml code as well. As I see it, the webview is loading the page, but it's just not visible on the screen.

Comment: @JosephusVillarey. I have added the XML code. Thank you. Please keep me posted with what more needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution to open the web page inside your activity:

First of all, i changed some property of your layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <GridView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Else the WebView won't be visible.

You must also add a class to take control over the os:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {   
    @Override
    /**
     * Take control over the loaded url so the url is open in the current Webview and not by the OS browser
     */
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
```

}

And your listener should look like this :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        CustomWebViewClient myCustomWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(myCustomWebViewClient);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

Hope it's what your are looking for.

EDIT : Another solution, which opens the webview inside a second activity (of the application):

I just made some change to your listener :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    String url;
    //The url changes accordingly to the button clicked
   switch (position) {
        case 0:  url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
                 break;
        case 1:  url = "http://yahoo.fr";
                 break;
        case 2:  url = "http://bing.com";
                 break;
        default: url = "http://google.com";
                 break;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class); 
    //used to pass the url to the next activity
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    startActivity(intent);//reference to start the activity
}
```

My second activy :

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity 
{   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         //calls the method from super class Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.second);          //sets the UI
        //the webview inside the second activity xml
        WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        CustomWebViewClient myCustomWebViewClient = new CustomWebViewClient();
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(myCustomWebViewClient);
        //get the url from the previous activity
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {   
        @Override
        /**
         * Take control over the loaded url so the url is open in the current Webview and not by the OS browser
         */
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I didn't touch the xml files.

As for the first solution, we need to override shouldOverrideUrlLoading in ordre to load the url in the right view.

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit. Your answer was so helpful. 

Mr. XST, can you please let me know if I wish to display the webpage in another activity, then do we have to change the following method:

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)

Comment: By other activity, I assume it's the default browser, in this case, as said by @JosephusVillarey, your method should look like this:
    
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
 {
  String url = "http://myawesomeurl.com";  
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));  
  startActivity(i);

 }

Comment: Whenever I click the second image or the third image, I get the same - http://microsoft.com page. I listed more urls in the onItemClick event:

myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.amazon.com");
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.microsoft.com");

What I thought was that if I clicked the second image in my GridView I should get amazon.com; and for third image: microsoft.com. But for all three clicks I am getting microsoft.com

I am finding this bit confusing. Why is this happening?

Comment: Simply use a switch statement in your listener :

 String url;
 switch (position) {
  case 0:
   url = "http://google.com";
  break;
  case 1:
   url = "http://yahoo.com";
   break;
  case 2:
   url = "http://bing.com";
   break;
  default:
   url = "http://microsoft.com";
  break;

Comment: Did you achieved what your were looking for @Niteesh?

Comment: Sorry, I had exams and hence did not respond. I edited the code and took your advice and it worked beautifully. Please check above (in question)to see the code. Thank you so much.

Comment: One last trouble. I tried another instance of this program. What I did was - created a new activity named Activity2 (Activity2.java) to display the webpage I do switch to Activity2 on the onClickEvent but the webpage is not seen. Can you please help me figure out why?

Comment: I appreciate you writing skills. You have been so systematic in your answers. Thank you for your answers and time.

Comment: I have posted the XML code for ACtivity2, java code for Activity2 and Java code for MainActivity that reference the onClickItem() event for webpage to be shown in Activity2 in my question.

Comment: I won't be able to get my hands on a computer before 5 fives days, be I will edit my first answer as soon as I go home to give you a solution

Comment: No problem. Meanwhile I will play around the solution given by Josephus Villarey. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your xml code the height for your webview and grid view is fill parent.
You must be able to load the page but gridview being fillparent its occupying the full screen.

make it wrap content.

And also i think it is better load webview in next activity if it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Agarwal is right - consider revising your layout, or open the web page in a separate activity instead.

Here's the code to open a web page from a url:

```
String url = "http://almondmendoza.com/android-applications/";  
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));  
startActivity(i);
```

edit:

To open the link from a new activity:

```
String url = "http://almondmendoza.com/android-applications/";
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("key_url", url);
startActivity(i);
```

`this` in `new Intent(this, Activity2.class);` is the context of your activity. If this code is inside an inner class, use `MyActivity1.this`

for Activity2, to get the url thrown by the Intent from the previous `startActivity` code,

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("key_url");
```

then you can do whatever you want with the url, like

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

all of these in `onCreate`

Comment: Thank you for the helpful insight. Please tell me where should I place this code?

Comment: put in inside gridview's setOnItemClickListener

Comment: As per your and Agrawal's suggestion, I created an Activity2 to display onClickEvent(). I do get to see the Activity2 view but no web page is being displayed. I tried many turnarounds but to no avail. What wrong am I doing? I have posted the code above. Can you please help me figure that out?

Comment: The code snippet i pasted was intended to open the default browser (or allow you to choose which browser to use, in case you have more than one installed) and load the site from there. If you want to open the site in another activity, check out my edited answer.